# Does Unity 5.4.3 supports backward compatibility with Unity 5.4.2?

Tags: unity

I'm currently using Unity 5.4.2 for my video game project, however my friend who assists me in the project uses Unity 5.4.3 instead.
Does Unity 5.4.3 supports backward compatibility with projects made with the previous version, in this case, Unity 5.4.2?

*NB: This is the first time I'm asking in Stack Exchange forum. I'm apologize for any mistakes in this question.*

Comment: If you use source control (i.e. `git`) then you have nothing to lose other than time.  Update Unity, test your project and if it fails then roll back (uinstall Unity and checkout your previous project commit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you were to update your unity editor to the newer version, it will re-process the project at startup. You should only expect to have problems when upgrading from a much older version than the current one (e.g. Unity 4 to 5) as APIs are revised to reflect major changes in the engine.

@Gnemlock has pointed out the possibility of bugs being introduced when updating to a newer version of Unity. While a noteworthy point, if your friend is successfully working on the project in 5.4.3, it is unlikely that joining him/her is likely to cause you headaches.

@DMGregory has reminded us of the one fundamental truth in these matters: **backing up your project** is the number one way to update with confidence.

Comment: On the contrary, I have personally seen Unity break projects during such minor updates, and have been advised countless times to refrain from updating between Unity X.Y.1 and Unity X.Y.2 *countless* times.

Comment: Of course, bugs can be introduced and Unity recommend not updating unless prompted. At the risk of getting anecdotal, what have you personally experienced?

Comment: Entire components breaking, default scripts breaking, scenes refusing to load, 50/50 crashes (I.e. started happening half the time), needless baking (attempts to bake light, proceeds through this process indefinetly - happens almost every time). I've also had projects *completely written off*. This was all after being *prompted* to update.

Comment: I think you're describing bugs introduced by the editor. I'm no stranger to these and share your frustration - it is certainly something to consider and I will update my answer to note this as a potential side-effect. Bugs notwithstanding, Unity is updated with backwards compatibility in mind so there shouldn't be anything inherently dangerous about updating if the OPs friend isn't already suffering.

Comment: I've heard some horror stories from other devs too after what should be minor updates. Bottom line: back up your project files first and test thoroughly after upgrading. Most things *should* update automatically with only minor fixups, but in the event of a significant problem you want to have easy access to roll back to the version you know.